# Insert html into web page using javascript's .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a template for a web site, and decided to try to use an external JS file to insert html into the top of the page for navigation (instead of having to copy and paste it every time)

I am trying to use (as the title states) The .innerHTML tag to do this so I can edit the code in whole.

Here it is:
**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML += '<script         language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "inline") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/down-    arrow-icon.jpg" height="25" width="25">';
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "inline";
    text.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/up-arrow-icon.jpg" height="25" width="25">';
}
} 
</script>
<body>

 <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();"><img     src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/down-arrow-icon.jpg" height="25" width="25"></a><span style="text-size: 30px;">Logo</span>

<div id="toggleText" class="navbar" style="display: none">
<div style="background-color: #8CBADB; text-align:center; height:25px; width:250px; border: .5px solid black;">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">About</a></div>
</div>
<br>
Content';
```

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
   </head>
  <div id="insert"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have double checked that I escaped the quotes, I ran it through [JSLint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php), and checked for possible syntax errors. I have so far come up with nothing. 
What am I going wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't add javascript to your page with innerHTML. I'm not even sure that works... You should add the elements to your page using document.createElement and document.addChild.  You completely need to change your approach.

Comment: your source html is not well formatted there's no <body> element in your mark-up.  I know you're trying to insert that from JavaScript but that not a good approach. If you have to insert mark-up into two sections of your document (one in the header and one in the document body than insert two separate blocks. When you load the html its not valid. The scripts then load and then try to insert into the document (which is malformed) - keep the mark-up valid and insert what you need separately

Comment: I am aware of the errors. This is not the exact code I mean to use. I only intend I add code into the <body> tag and use the head tag for calling the js file to insert it. I apologize if this makes it tough to addres the problem, but my only resource right now is the iPad and it is not easy to code on, I just use it for making the bare bones of what I'm going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1. You need to assign only in line no 1, remove the concatenation sign `+`

   `document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML` +=
2. At line no 7 and 11 avoid using single single quote, instead that use double quotes, It's making the wrong syntax, because it will make end of the expression here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign but not to concatenate.

```
document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML += 
// Remove + from here----------------------^^
```

Comment: First thing I noticed